# PrimeVue DataTable Filter on date column error: value.toDateString is not a function

Tags: vue.js, primevue

Versions:
npm: 9.5.1
Vue: 3.2.45
PrimeVue: 3.42.0

Hi!

I'm trying to use filters on a date column in a DataTable. I know this is a bit long, but it shows what I've tried.

For my date column (header==<name of date column>), I'm using the html below. There are other dtypes in my data, which are omitted here for clarity, but the "full" html (at least for the DataTable object) is at the bottom.

```
<template 
  v-if="getType(header) === 'date'" 
  #body="{ data }">
  {{ formatDate(data[header]) }}
</template>
<template #filter="{ filterModel }">
  <Calendar
    v-if="getType(header) === 'date'"
    v-model="filterModel.value" 
    class="p-column-filter"
    type="text"
    dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" 
    placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
  />
</template>
```

If I use this formatDate const function basically identical to the one in the [Advanced filters section in the docs](https://primevue.org/datatable/#advanced_filter) with the locale changed to reflect my date format (I know, typing as any is a bad idea):

```
const formatDate = (value: any) => {
  return value.toLocaleDateString('fr-CA', {
    day: '2-digit',
    month: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric'
  });
};
```

The component doesn't render and I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: value.toLocaleDateString is not a function
    at Proxy.formatDate (QueryTable.vue:131:18)
    at QueryTable.vue:190:18
    at Object.renderFnWithContext [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:852:19)
    at slots.<computed> (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2963:38)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:919:19)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5631:57)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:187:25)
    at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5745:56)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5759:9)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5541:9)
```

So clearly that value is not a date object. So I modified to this:

```
const formatDate = (value: any) => {
  return new Date(value).toLocaleDateString('fr-CA', {
    day: '2-digit',
    month: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric'
  });
};
```

Then the table loads, but when I filter, I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: value.toDateString is not a function
    at dateIs (api.esm.js:209:26)
    at Proxy.executeLocalFilter (datatable.esm.js:4079:20)
    at Proxy.filter (datatable.esm.js:4020:51)
    at Proxy.processedData (datatable.esm.js:5421:37)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:187:25)
    at get value [as value] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1150:39)
    at Object.get [as processedData] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3470:30)
    at Proxy.render16 (datatable.esm.js:5610:25)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:898:44)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5702:34)
```

api.esm.js:209:26 shows `return value.toDateString() === filter.toDateString();`. I thought, maybe the api is expecting a Date object?
So I tried this:

```
const formatDate = (value: any) => {
  return new Date(value)
};
```

Now my column has a format like so `Mon Nov 06 2023 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`, but I get the same error as above when I filter.

Anyways, at the very least, there seems to be something omitted from the "full code" in the [Advanced filters section in the docs](https://primevue.org/datatable/#advanced_filter). Since this appears to work on the docs page, I don't think there is a bug. Any help is much appreciated!

"Full" html:

```
<DataTable
  class="p-datatable-sm"
  scrollable
  scrollHeight="flex"
  striped-rows
  paginator
  sortMode="multiple"
  removableSort
  :multiSortMeta="[{field: 'run_id', order: -1}, {field: 'sample_id', order: -1}]"
  :rows="25"
  :rows-per-page-options="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
  :value="data"
  v-model:filters="filters"
  v-on:filter="onFilter"
  filterDisplay="menu"
  stateStorage="local" 
  stateKey="filters"
  onkeypress="handle(event)"
>
  <template #empty> No data matches filters. </template>
  <Column
    v-for="header in data"
    :key="header"
    :filterField="header"
    :showClearButton="false"
    sortable
    :field="header"
    :header="ucwords(header)"
    :dataType="getType(header)"
    filterEvent="enter"
    >
    <template 
      v-if="getType(header) === 'date'" 
      #body="{ data }">
      {{ formatDate(data[header]) }}
    </template>
    <template 
      v-else 
      #body="{ data }">
      {{ data[header] }}
    </template>
    <template #filter="{ filterModel }">
      <InputText
        v-if="getType(header) === 'text'"
        v-model="filterModel.value" 
        class="p-column-filter"
        type="text" 
      />
      <Calendar
        v-else-if="getType(header) === 'date'"
        v-model="filterModel.value" 
        class="p-column-filter"
        type="text"
        dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" 
        placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
      />
      <InputNumber 
        v-else-if="getType(header) === 'numeric'"
        v-model="filterModel.value" 
        class="p-column-filter"
        type="number"
      />
    </template>
  </Column>
</DataTable>
```

Comment: `v-on:filter="onFilter"` what is this function? Is it relevant to your date filtering?  The way the doc example works is on mount it converts all the initial date strings, e.g. `2017-05-03` to date objects with [new Date constructor seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pecmge?file=src%2FApp.vue%3AL328). The example table then only ever works with these date objects and therefore doesn't need to worry about adding conversions inside different functions. It's not clear what _your_ data looks like as you've not shown much of your JS code.

Comment: @yoduh you are correct. my data came from a postgresql server so the date column (though psql knows it is a date) was strings in my app. i assumed incorrectly that the filter uses #body, but apparently not. once i transformed values in my date column to js Date type, it works! if you post this as an answer i'll accept it so you get the credit. thanks for throwing out ideas!

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapdates = (data) => {
  return [...(data || [])].map((d) => {
   d.created_at = new Date(d.created_at);
    d.updated_at = new Date(d.updated_at);
    return d;
  });
};
const formatDate = (value) => {
 return value.toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
    day: "2-digit",
    month: "2-digit",
    year: "numeric",
  });
};

jorStore.getJOR().then((data) => (requests.value = mapdates(data)));




<Column
    header="Birth Date"
    filterField="patbdate"
    dataType="date"
    style="min-width: 10rem"
  >
    <template #body="{ data }">
      {{ formatDate(data.patbdate) }}
    </template>
    <template #filter="{ filterModel }">
      <Calendar
        v-model="filterModel.value"
        dateFormat="mm/dd/yyyy"
        placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
        mask="99/99/9999"
      />
    </template>
  </Column>
```

Comment: call the function mapdates b4 u save ur data on ur variable